# Finding the longest power subsequence

Tags: data-structures, hash, hash-tables

A power sequence is a sequence containing consecutive powers of a number starting from power one. for example $3^1, 3^2, 3^3$ is a power sequence. The question is to find the length of the longest power sequence in an array in $O(n)$ time. Note that the sequence is a subsequence of the array.

For example, in the array $1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8$,
the longest power sequence is $2,4,8$.

I wanted to write a hash function that gives similar values for powers of the same number, but this does not guarantee that powers are consecutive.

Comment: Scan the array from right to left. At any given point in time, you have the earliest occurrence of each value in $A_{t+1},\ldots,A_n$ in a hash table, and you can use this to find the longest power subsequence starting at $A_t$. However, this still runs in time $\Omega(n\log n)$, unless you put some restrictions on the size of the integers involved (which we usually do!) – consider for example $2,4,8,16,\ldots,2^n$, where the sum of length of all subsequences starting at each element is $\Theta(n\log n)$.

Comment: if we have some sort of restriction, could you please explain more about how we can find the longest power subsequence using the hash table? @YuvalFilmus

Comment: It's exactly the same algorithm outlined in my comment.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus It is an interesting answer. And, for the sequence $2$, $4$, $8$, $\dotsc$, $2^n$, the sum of length of sequences in indeed $\Theta(n \log n)$. However, it does not mean that the algorithm will perform in $O(n \log n)$ time. The algorithm will still go through every entry of the array for each $A_{t}$ unless we restrict $t \leq \log n$. Is that the case?

Comment: I don't think so. The hash table prevents the need to scan through the entire array.